# Application.Exit() doesn't dispose a used dll

Tags: c#, windows-ce

On a Windows CE application, I'm using Application.Exit() for closing the application but one of the dll's that I use isn't disposed and causing me problem when I try to re run the application.

Is this because Application.Exit() doesn't dispose it or I'm still using it somewhere?

What is the correct way to close an application?

Thank you

Edit: Ok to give more details, Here is my scenario:

Main page -> Lets call this A

Idle page -> Lets call this B

Page that closes the app -> Lets call this C

On app.start, A opens B and B opens C with the help of a thread, this is why I'm using application.Exit(). Maybe I should go to parent.parent.parent and call close() on main form? :)

Comment: Are you sure that it is exiting after you call Application.Exit()? What is the problem you see when you try to re-run the application?

Comment: I get an error: "myDll.dll is being used by another process." Yes I'm sure it happens after I quit by Application.Exit()

Answer (score 2):

Normally closing the main form is chosen way to leave an application. Application.Exit was historically a less preferred way as it semi-implied more drastic shutdown as some of the close events are not triggered (such as mainform.close etc)

Comment: Depends if b and c are modal or not.

Comment: I would have your form C then tell form A to close. This will close the application in a more sensible method - as it will ask other forms to close, and they can close all parts they have open too

Comment: @Pabuc: Can you try something like foreach (Form var in Application.OpenForms)
            {
var.Close();
            }

Comment: @V4Vendetta Windows CE doesn't support Application.OpenForms

Answer (score 2):

In a typical application the `Application.Exit` call will only cause the main thread to shut down.  Background threads, particularly non-ui ones, will not be terminated via this call.  If any are left running the process will continue.

This could very well be the reason you still see resources being held after calling `Application.Exit`.  One way to quickly verify is to see if the process is still running after `Application.Exit` runs.  If so then this is almost certainly your problem.

Comment: And what is your suggestion? The page that closes the app is on a different thread than main thread..

Comment: @Pabuc my suggestion would be to create a central Close method which both calls Application.Close and signals the background threads to terminate